# Simplify combined CSS

Tags: css

In our platform we have standard CSS templates. In a specific implementation, customers can override the css by making their own CSS. Those two CSS files will be combined (the custom CSS appended to the standard) and minified. This all works well.

However, that CSS will contain a lot of double declarations. The standard CSS will contain a .body declaration (for example) but the custom css will have one too. The CSS will be needlessly big and hard to interpret by the browser.

Does anyone know a tool/library that will fix these double declarations (at runtime)? I have seen a lot of tools that will combine and minify CSS, but not this.

Comment: Questions asking us to suggest, find or recommend a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow Stack Overflow

Comment: Did you find what you were looking for?

Comment: No, I did not find any suitable library for C#

Answer (score 0):

Cssnano is a library that I use in grunt, you should be able to bend it to your will. http://cssnano.co

Here is a list of optimisations for cssnano http://cssnano.co/optimisations/

There are a few more CSS post processors out there though.